# How to change Ko-fi donation widget position?

Tags: javascript, html, widget, position

I am writing a small web app and I would like to add a donation button by using the [ko-fi donation widget button](https://ko-fi.com/Manage/donation-widget-setup). The result is something like this:

[image]

My goal is to change it's position for example by lowering the button to 5px.
I tried with some javascript but it looks like it only works if I do it from the browser console.

```
<script src='https://storage.ko-fi.com/cdn/scripts/overlay-widget.js'></script>
  <script>
    kofiWidgetOverlay.draw('federicogentile90', {
      'type': 'floating-chat',
      'floating-chat.donateButton.text': 'Support me',
      'floating-chat.donateButton.background-color': '#fcbf47',
      'floating-chat.donateButton.text-color': '#323842',
    });
    // WHAT I TRIED TO DO!
    window.onload = function() {
      let kofiElement = document.getElementsByClassName("floatingchat-container-wrap");
      console.log(kofiElement);
      // Modify bottom position
      kofiElement[0].style.bottom = "5px";
      };
  </script>
```

Do you know how the widget can be moved around the html page please?

Comment: This link could be very helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N7v0yvdkIHg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve my goal by using the following trick: instead of using the floating button provided by ko-fi, you can use the create a [ko-fi button](https://ko-fi.com/manage/widgets?src=sidemenu) as an image so that when you click on it the [donation panel](https://ko-fi.com/Manage/donation-widget-setup) opens up as a modal.

Here is what it looks like right now:

[image]

As you can see now the button is in the navbar but when I click on it the payment form appears on the screen.

Here is the code in case you need it:

```
<a data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal"><img height='36' style='border:0px;height:36px;' src='https://storage.ko-fi.com/cdn/kofi4.png?v=3' border='0' alt='Buy Me a Coffee at ko-fi.com' /></a>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
         <div class="modal-content">
             <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <iframe id='kofiframe' src='https://ko-fi.com/your-kofi-link' style='border:none;width:100%;padding:4px;background:#f9f9f9;' height='712' title='federicogentile90'></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Make sure to update the iframe with your ko-fi link!

Answer (score 3):

You can add this CSS afterwards:

```
<style>
.floatingchat-container-wrap { bottom: 11px; }
.floating-chat-kofi-popup-iframe { bottom: 70px; }
</style>
```

If you'd like to get it positioned on the right (which was my goal) then:

```
<style>
.floatingchat-container-wrap { left:unset; right: 16px; }
.floating-chat-kofi-popup-iframe { left:unset; right: 16px; }
</style>
```

Comment: This seems to work up until a media break-point kicks in at around 1000px and no matter what media queries / break-points I try to implement, the widget re-positions itself to the bottom left of the screen. Any ideas on how to address this?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to accomplish putting the donate button in the bottom right corner using the following css. This builds off Emmy's answer, but adds a few missing classes that affected mobile and low width views.

```
<script src='https://storage.ko-fi.com/cdn/scripts/overlay-widget.js'></script>
<script>
    kofiWidgetOverlay.draw('dupras', {
        'type': 'floating-chat',
        'floating-chat.donateButton.text': 'Support Me',
        'floating-chat.donateButton.background-color': '#00b9fe',
        'floating-chat.donateButton.text-color': '#fff'
    });
</script>   
<style>
    .floatingchat-container-wrap { left: unset; right: 50px; width: 50%; }
    .floatingchat-container-wrap-mobi { left: unset; right: 50px; width: 50%;}
    .floating-chat-kofi-popup-iframe { left: unset; right: 50px; }
    .floating-chat-kofi-popup-iframe-mobi { left: unset; right: 50px; }
    .floating-chat-kofi-popup-iframe-closer-mobi { left: unset; right: 50px; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// const iFrame = getContainerFrameId(); // seems not in scope for you at the time you run it
const iFrame=document.querySelector("iframe[id^='kofi-wo-container']");
iFrame.style.position="absolute";
iFrame.style.bottom = "5px";
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, but I get the following error:
caught ReferenceError: getContainerFrameId is not defined